# GLUT mouse interaction

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

can any body tel m how to get more then 1 point x value and y value with mouse interaction ?i want to get x1,y1 value and for another point x2 ,y2

```
void mouse(int button ,int state,int x,int y)
{
    if(button==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN){
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to get two points? You have two cursors?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really done much at all with OpenGL, but couldn't you just use a && (x + 1) or however much you wanted to increase it, when checking the value of x?

Answer (score 0):

> can any body tel m how to get more then 1 point x value and y value with mouse interaction?

You mean like if the user clicks into the screen several times? If so: Create an array or a list of points and append the incoming points as they come.

If you want to get more than one point for a single click (which is exactly one point on the screen) you'll have to tell us, what exactly it is you're trying to do.

Do you think about multitouch? Well GLUT doesn't have support for that; you'll have to switch to an application framework that can work with multiple pointer devices. Or you, or somebody else, adds multitouch support to GLUT, introducing a new event handler `MultiPointer` that supplies a pointer index. But that's just hypothetical.